# Strange diophantine equation involving seventh powers

Tags: number-theory

Consider the diophantine equation $$\frac{x^7 - y^7}{z^7 - t^7} = 3$$ where $x$, $y$, $z$ and $t$ are integers.

Can one prove that the number of coprime 4-tuples satisfying this equation is finite?

Comment: Do you know any primitve solution at all ?

Comment: No, I don't. Embarrassing!